# Alguém pode me explicar um parte desse codigo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop, for

O código em questão é o de baixo, boa parte dele eu estou entendendo mais o loop for me confundiu, ele recebe a sequencia da variável, mas no print, ele informa exatamente a sequencia que o usuário digitou, como ele sabe qual é a "letra" na variável **index** ?

```
def jogar():
    print("******************************")
    print("**BEM VINDO AO JOGO DA FORCA**")
    print("******************************")

palavra_secreta = "brasil"

while True:
    chute = input("Qual a letra? ")
    chute = chute.strip()
    index = 0
    for i in palavra_secreta:
        if(chute.upper() == i.upper()):
            print("Encontrada sua letra {} na posição {}".format(chute.upper(), index))
        index = index + 1

 if(__name__ == "__main__"):
     jogar()
```

Comment: Uma string é um iterator, podes ver isso como uma string é um array/list: https://repl.it/repls/TruthfulBusyFanworms

Answer (score 3):

Na parte do for ele percorre com "i" cada letra da palavra secreta no caso "brasil" sendo assim em cada volta que o for da ele vai seguir a sequencia "b" depois "r" depois "a" e assim por diante. 
Exemplo:

minha letra digitada: "s"

posição -> [index]

posição 0 do for [0] letra "b" 
 posição 1 do for [1] letra "r" 
 posição 2 do for [2] letra "a"
  posição 3 do for [3] letra "s" -->Encontrada minha letra "s" na posição 4 index 3 
 posição 4 do for [4] letra "i"
 posição 5 do for [5] letra "l"

no caso o "i" faz o papel de ir pegando cada letra uma por uma,
depois no if ele compara se a letra digitada é igual a alguma letra da palavra secreta, se no caso o cara digitou a letra "r" quando o for rodar cada letra da palavra secreta irá encontrar essa letra, no print ele mostra a letra encontrada e o index dela que vai pegar a posição do for

Comment: Ok, obrigado, estava pensando na mesma coisa tentando entender, mas não conseguia juntar os pensamentos, valeu pela explicação